# How to scroll up a view above a listview along with it?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a relative layout above a listview with multiple textviews and imageviews in it. These textviews,imageviews and listview data is binded dynamically after calling an asynctask.

I need to scroll up the relative layout along with the listview as it occupies almost half of the screen size.

I tried addheaderview, but to use that the view should be added dynamically. I have declared my Relativelayout above listview in XML as it has many children and it is difficult to adjust the views dynamically.
I know that I cannot use a listview inside a scrollview.

I tried answers in here, but none of them worked. Can someone suggest a good approach to solve this?

Comment: Well if you are aware about `addHeaderView` then simplest solution is make a xml file and put what ever you have to for the header and add it dynamically.

Comment: What is the problem with adding header view dynamically?

Comment: @SpringBreaker Thanks a lot buddy. Solved my prob.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding the ScrollView in complete Realative Layout

Answer (score -1):

i used this it worked for me , Use `ListView` inside `ScrollView`

use this code for dynamic Height for `ListView`

//Create a Class

```
 public class ListUtility {

public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}

}
```

use it in your Activity

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
ListUtility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView);
```